# How can I link MacPort's pyqt to Enthought's Python distribution?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, macports, enthought

I have successfully compiled py27-pyqt4 from Macports, but it is compiled against the system python 2.7. But my standard working environment is Enthought's Python distribution (EPD) 7.2-2.
The system python (/usr/bin/python) is a Python 2.7.1, but EPD's Python is a Python 2.7.2.

Can I link this 2.7.1-compiled pyqt without problems to my EPD? If so, how?
And if not, how can I compile MacPorts using the EPD's python?

Answer (score 1):

I had also hard time trying to install pyqt4 linked to EPD using macport (for some reason, I couldn't make macport to build pyqt4 with the correct PPC architecture of my powerbook G4 ...).

I ended up by building pyqt4 directly from source, and [this post](http://www.noktec.be/python/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-osx) as well as [this post](http://www.oak-tree.us/blog/index.php/2009/05/12/pyqt-mac) have been very useful. Just change the target install diectory `/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages` with the one in your EPD folder. Worked for me.